# How to align swiftUI List perfectly?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I have a simple view, a rectangle and a list of numbers, `what I want is both of this have the same 20 horizontal padding`, it is simple for rectangle but I don't know how to set a proper value for list.
I use `PlainListStyle()` but in the iPhone SE and Pro Max have different horizontal padding that makes UI to be different from iPhone to iPhone that shouldn't be.

[image]
[image]

things I tried :

1. Different `list style` with different padding and setting different width value.
   2.Set `EdgeInsets` for rows in list to find the perfect value.

.listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 6, bottom: 20, trailing: 11))

but non of them worked.
Do you know how can I align list and rectangle by 20 padding?

What am I missing?

```
VStack(spacing: 0) {
            
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(.red)
                .frame(maxWidth : .infinity)
                .frame( height: 100)
                .padding(.horizontal,20)
            
            List {
                ForEach((1...20).reversed(), id: \.self) { number in
                    
                        Text("\(number)")
                      
                }
            }
            .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
            //          .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
            //            .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
            //            .listStyle(InsetListStyle())
            //           .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
          

            
            
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach can be a possible way for solving your issue:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var size: CGFloat? = nil
    @State private var backgroundSize: CGFloat? = nil
    @State private var paddingValue: CGFloat = .zero
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(.red)
                .frame(maxWidth : .infinity)
                .frame(height: 100)
                .padding(.horizontal, paddingValue)
            
            
            List {
                
                if (size == nil) {
                    
                    GeometryReader { proxy in
                        
                        Color.clear
                            .onAppear(perform: { size = proxy.size.width })
                        
                    }
                    .frame(height: .zero)
                }
                
                ForEach((1...20).reversed(), id: \.self) { number in Text("\(number)") }
                
            }
            .background(
                
                GeometryReader { proxy in
                    
                    Color.clear
                        .onAppear(perform: { backgroundSize = proxy.size.width })
                    
                })
            .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
            
        }
        .onChange(of: size, perform: { newValue in
            
            if let unwrappedValue: CGFloat = newValue, let backgroundSize: CGFloat = backgroundSize {
                paddingValue = (backgroundSize - unwrappedValue)/2.0
            }
 
        })
        
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, you fixed the rectangle padding while it has the right 20 padding in your solution you don't fix the list padding you change the rectangle padding based on the list padding, and this Is not what I want.

Comment: @fdvfarzin: I think the other answer is better approach for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    VStack(spacing: 0) {
        Rectangle()
            .foregroundColor(.red)
            .frame(maxWidth : .infinity)
            .frame( height: 100)
            // .padding(.horizontal,20) // Remove the padding from here
        
        List {
            ForEach((1...20).reversed(), id: \.self) { number in
                Text("\(number)")
            }
            .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 10, leading: 0, bottom: 10, trailing: 10)) // Set the EdgeInsets(leading: 0)
        }
        .listStyle(.plain) // Use a plain list style
    }
    .padding(.leading, 20) // Put the padding here
```

This gives you a plain list, and zeroing your edge inset puts it right up to the edge of the view. At that point, the rectangle and list are aligned. Then pad the `VStack` by 20.